# Pandoc 1.13.2 outputs html table as text

Tags: markdown, pandoc

Take this tst.md file (in Markdown)

```
% Test document

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr >
            <th>A</td>
            <th>B</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr >
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

End of test file
```

and run it with pandoc 1.13.2 to transform it into html

```
pandoc -s "test.md" -o test.html
```

The created test.html contains

```
<table>
<pre><code>&lt;thead&gt;
  &lt;tr &gt;
    &lt;th&gt;A&lt;/td&gt;
    &lt;th&gt;B&lt;/td&gt;
  &lt;/tr&gt;
&lt;/thead&gt;
&lt;tbody&gt;
 &lt;tr &gt;
    &lt;td&gt;1&lt;/td&gt;
    &lt;td&gt;2&lt;/td&gt;
  &lt;/tr&gt;
 &lt;tr &gt;
    &lt;td&gt;3&lt;/td&gt;
    &lt;td&gt;4&lt;/td&gt;
  &lt;/tr&gt;
&lt;/tbody&gt;</code></pre>
</table>
```

A `<pre><code>` tag is inserted after `<table>`. The following html code is encoded and displays as code not as a table.

The [pandoc website](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#raw-html) says: Standard markdown allows you to include HTML “blocks”: blocks of HTML between balanced tags that are separated from the surrounding text with blank lines, and start and end at the left margin. Within these blocks, everything is interpreted as HTML, not markdown;

The same result comes out if you do on Pandoc's trial site http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try

The older version 1.11.1 worked fine. But 1.11.1 is no longer available on Pandoc's website (as a MSI installer).

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reference the section for the `markdown_in_html_blocks` extension, which is [clearly says that Pandoc Markdown doesn't behave this way by default](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#extension-markdown_in_html_blocks):

> Pandoc behaves this way when the `markdown_strict` format is used; but by default, pandoc interprets material between HTML block tags as markdown.

Use the strict input format by adding `-f markdown_strict` to your command.

Answer (score 1):

Tried it with all tags to the left (no indentation) which works on the trial site and with pandoc 1.13.2.
It seems that pandoc 1.13.2 requires total absence indentation in raw html where as in previous versions html would stay raw if the first (and last) tag had no spaces or tab before.