# How to convert tables in markdown file into html file using pandoc

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to convert markdown files into `html` using `pandoc`,
This is the markdown table format in .md file:

```
| Name | Unit | Symbol |
|----|----|----|
| variable A |  | $a$ | 
| variable B |  | $b$ |
| variable C |  | $\mu$ |
```

```
pandoc --toc --standalone --mathjax -f markdown_strict -t html file_name.md -o file_name.html --metadata pagetitle="page title"
```

but the tables are shown as text. I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793557/pandoc-1-13-2-outputs-html-table-as-text) solution as well but I still have tables as normal text without table borders in `html`. However directly exporting through `ReText` the `html` shows tables without any issue. How do I get the tables in `html` file while using `pandoc`?

Answer (score 0):

John Gruber's original Markdown, which is the format that pandoc assumes when converting with `-f markdown_strict`, has no syntax for tables. The table format in the input is called "pipe table", and you'll need to enable the respective Markdown extension to make pandoc parse it:

```bash
pandoc -f markdown_strict+pipe_tables ...
```

Alternatively, you could use a different Markdown format like pandoc's default Markdown (`-f markdown`), GitHub Flavored Markdown (`-f gfm`), or extended CommonMark (`-f commonmark_x`), as those all have support for pipe tables baked in.

All of those formats also support the dollar syntax for math, which you'll probably want enabled as well. Enabling it with `markdown_strict` is possible by appending `+tex_math_dollars` to the format definition.

Comment: I get `Unknown extension:  pipe_tables` while using `+pip_tables`

Comment: Looks like a typo: `+pipe_tables` vs `+pip_tables`

Comment: no no, I've been using `+pipe_tables` only, typo was just in my comment here

Comment: Try quoting the format. I think your shell might be treating the `+` in special way.

Comment: it does not work with quoting the format

Comment: I'm at a loss. My advice would be to use `-f gfm`.